# How do symbolic references resolve to direct references in Class loading phase in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

In class file's constant pool a class reference is show as CONSTANT_Class_info structure. How does it get resolved to direct memory address? 
The memory space which CONSTANT_Class_info structure points to and memory address occupied are not the same...

Comment: There is no relationship between the space occupied in a class file and the memory occupied at runtime. It’s not clear why this should be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The CONSTANT_Class_info structure contains an index pointing to a string/utf8 value in the same constant pool. This string/utf8 contains the name of the class to be resolved. If the class in question has a already been loaded then the JVM uses some kind of data structure/lookup function to map the name to a class, while if the class has not already been loaded, then the name is used to find the class in question on the classpath, and load it.